# Image preview while uploading image

Tags: file-upload, filereader

I am using the following script to preview image during upload. But it is notworking and not changing the src attribute.

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#field_header_image 1_preview')
                .attr('src',e.target.result)
                    .width(150)
                   .height(200);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Please check the JS Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/sw6fW/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <meta charset=utf-8 />
   <title>Auto Image Preview</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
  <img id="image_prev" src="#" alt="your image" />


<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function (e) {
     $('#image_prev')
         .attr('src', e.target.result)
         .width(150)
         .height(150);
    };
   reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

refer to this link to get your question  answered

http://rameshworpathak.com.np/preview-uploaded-image-using-jquery-while-uploading-image/

Hopefully it will help you

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.